# Does AOP-style transaction demarcation actually work with Hibernate 4 and Spring 3.1?

Tags: java, spring-aop, spring-3, hibernate-4.x

I am trying to get hibernate-release-4.1.8.Final working with Spring 3.1.3.RELEASE.

Spring appContext is as follows:

```
<bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="configLocation">
        <value>
            classpath:hibernate.cfg.xml
        </value>
    </property>
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <value>
            hibernate.show_sql=true
            hibernate.format_sql=true
            hibernate.current_session_context_class=thread
        </value>
    </property>
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
</bean>
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.LazyConnectionDataSourceProxy">
    <property name="targetDataSource">
        <ref local="mainDataSource"/>
    </property>
</bean>
<!-- mysql with bonecp thread pooling using a lazy jdbc connection -->
<bean id="mainDataSource" class="com.jolbox.bonecp.BoneCPDataSource" destroy-method="close">
    <property name="driverClass" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
    <property name="jdbcUrl" value="jdbc:mysql:..."
    ...
</bean>

<bean id="txManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"/>
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
</bean>

<tx:advice id="txAdvice" transaction-manager="txManager">
    <tx:attributes>
        <tx:method name="*" rollback-for="ServletException" propagation="REQUIRED"/>
    </tx:attributes>
</tx:advice>
<aop:config>
    <aop:pointcut id="serviceMethods" expression="execution(* com.mytest.service.*.*(..))"/>
    <aop:advisor advice-ref="txAdvice" pointcut-ref="serviceMethods"/>
</aop:config>
```

The above is fairly similar to the latest Spring docs showing Hibernate 4 integration.  Note, I prefer to use a spring-aop cross-cut rather than `@Transaction` annotations.  According to Spring docs, `hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager` should support both styles of declarative config: annotation and XML.  But does it really?  Here's what happens:

Common DAO structure:

```
public abstract class MyHibernateDAOImpl<T> implements BaseDAO<T> {
    // spring-injected sessionFactory
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    public void setSessionFactory(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
        this.sessionFactory = sessionFactory;
    }

    public Session getSession() {
        //ignore orm.hibernate4.SessionFactoryUtils for now -- will be explained later
        //Session s = SessionFactoryUtils.openSession(sessionFactory);

        //spring-recommended approach to getting session
        Session s = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        return s;
    }

    //basic query
    public List<UserState> getSomeData() {
        Query query = getSession().createQuery("from SomeData");
        return query.list();
    }
}
```

No annotations are used. My understanding is that `HibernateTransactionManager` in `orm.hibernate4` will join the aop-created Transaction to `ThreadLocal` and bind it to the Session. Seems like the bind never happens? Or perhaps I'm not dealing with the `Session` I think I'm dealing with?

Assume that my app is a standard Spring-mvc app with the spring-web libs coming from the same release bundle as what I'm showing. Further, Views make use of `org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.support.OpenSessionInViewInterceptor` for extending session life-time and I have no issues there...

Running in Tomcat6 produces the following DEBUG...

```
[2012-11-10 03:08:59,864] INFO [http-8443-exec-3] MyController.logRequest(273) | Session GET /data/InitialData
[2012-11-10 03:08:59,887] DEBUG [http-8443-exec-3] HibernateTransactionManager.doGetTransaction(290) | Found thread-bound Session [SessionImpl(PersistenceContext[entityKeys=[],collectionKeys=[]];ActionQueue[insertions=[] updates=[] deletions=[] collectionCreations=[] collectionRemovals=[] collectionUpdates=[] unresolvedInsertDependencies=UnresolvedEntityInsertActions[]])] for Hibernate transaction
[2012-11-10 03:08:59,889] DEBUG [http-8443-exec-3] AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.getTransaction(365) | Creating new transaction with name [com.betterment.service.user.impl.UserStateServiceImpl.getAllStates]: PROPAGATION_REQUIRED,ISOLATION_DEFAULT,-ServletException
[2012-11-10 03:08:59,889] DEBUG [http-8443-exec-3] HibernateTransactionManager.doBegin(352) | Preparing JDBC Connection of Hibernate Session [SessionImpl(PersistenceContext[entityKeys=[],collectionKeys=[]];ActionQueue[insertions=[] updates=[] deletions=[] collectionCreations=[] collectionRemovals=[] collectionUpdates=[] unresolvedInsertDependencies=UnresolvedEntityInsertActions[]])]
[2012-11-10 03:08:59,915] DEBUG [http-8443-exec-3] AbstractTransactionImpl.begin(158) | begin
[2012-11-10 03:08:59,915] DEBUG [http-8443-exec-3] LogicalConnectionImpl.obtainConnection(295) | Obtaining JDBC connection
[2012-11-10 03:08:59,916] DEBUG [http-8443-exec-3] LogicalConnectionImpl.obtainConnection(301) | Obtained JDBC connection
[2012-11-10 03:08:59,916] DEBUG [http-8443-exec-3] JdbcTransaction.doBegin(69) | initial autocommit status: true
[2012-11-10 03:08:59,916] DEBUG [http-8443-exec-3] JdbcTransaction.doBegin(71) | disabling autocommit
[2012-11-10 03:08:59,921] DEBUG [http-8443-exec-3] HibernateTransactionManager.doBegin(413) | Exposing Hibernate transaction as JDBC transaction [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.proxy.ConnectionProxyHandler@76566fb[valid=true]]
```

So far so good... A Transaction is created, we have a connection and there is even verbiage that a thread-bound session was found.  The log output lands my debug cursor inside the `DAO.getSomeData` method, right before `getSession()` is called and right before I create a query and pull a list().

Now, when `getSession()` is called a `Session` is returned - but cannot be inspected by debugger - odd.  When attempting to create an hql query from the `Session`, `Transaction` rolls back - implying that it was not actually bound to `ThreadLocal`:

```
[2012-11-10 03:16:06,972] DEBUG [http-8443-exec-3] AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processRollback(843) | Initiating transaction rollback
[2012-11-10 03:16:06,973] DEBUG [http-8443-exec-3] HibernateTransactionManager.doRollback(496) | Rolling back Hibernate transaction on Session [SessionImpl(PersistenceContext[entityKeys=[],collectionKeys=[]];ActionQueue[insertions=[] updates=[] deletions=[] collectionCreations=[] collectionRemovals=[] collectionUpdates=[] unresolvedInsertDependencies=UnresolvedEntityInsertActions[]])]
[2012-11-10 03:16:06,973] DEBUG [http-8443-exec-3] AbstractTransactionImpl.rollback(203) | rolling back
[2012-11-10 03:16:06,974] DEBUG [http-8443-exec-3] JdbcTransaction.doRollback(164) | rolled JDBC Connection
[2012-11-10 03:16:06,974] DEBUG [http-8443-exec-3] JdbcTransaction.releaseManagedConnection(126) | re-enabling autocommit
[2012-11-10 03:16:06,982] DEBUG [http-8443-exec-3] HibernateTransactionManager.doCleanupAfterCompletion(564) | Not closing pre-bound Hibernate Session [SessionImpl(PersistenceContext[entityKeys=[],collectionKeys=[]];ActionQueue[insertions=[] updates=[] deletions=[] collectionCreations=[] collectionRemovals=[] collectionUpdates=[] unresolvedInsertDependencies=UnresolvedEntityInsertActions[]])] after transaction
[2012-11-10 03:16:06,983] DEBUG [http-8443-exec-3] SessionImpl.disconnect(564) | Disconnecting session
[2012-11-10 03:16:06,983] DEBUG [http-8443-exec-3] LogicalConnectionImpl.releaseConnection(314) | Releasing JDBC connection
[2012-11-10 03:16:06,983] DEBUG [http-8443-exec-3] LogicalConnectionImpl.releaseConnection(332) | Released JDBC connection
[2012-11-10 03:16:06,983] DEBUG [http-8443-exec-3] ConnectionProxyHandler.physicalConnectionReleased(219) | HHH000163: Logical connection releasing its physical connection
[2012-11-10 03:16:06,984] DEBUG [http-8443-exec-3] ConnectionProxyHandler.physicalConnectionReleased(219) | HHH000163: Logical connection releasing its physical connection
[2012-11-10 03:16:06,984] DEBUG [http-8443-exec-3] ConnectionProxyHandler.physicalConnectionReleased(219) | HHH000163: Logical connection releasing its physical connection
[2012-11-10 03:16:06,997] DEBUG [http-8443-exec-3] OpenSessionInViewInterceptor.afterCompletion(141) | Closing Hibernate Session in OpenSessionInViewInterceptor
[2012-11-10 03:16:06,999] ERROR [http-8443-exec-3] ErrorFilter.doFilter(50) | Unexpected error in session 'mySession' javax.servlet.ServletException: org.hibernate.HibernateException: createQuery is not valid without active transaction
```

Next variant I tried was to go back to the `SessionFactoryUtils`. It works but seems to have a major side-effect. Note that this is the diminished `orm.hibernate4.SessionFactoryUtils` and not hibernate3's one. This `SessionFactory` only exposes an `openSession` and `closeSession`. With this factory, `getSession()` looks like:

```
public Session getSession() {
    //try with orm.hibernate4.SessionFactoryUtils
    Session s = SessionFactoryUtils.openSession(sessionFactory);
    return s;
}
```

With `SessionFactoryUtils` running, I do see the `QueryTranslator` kicking in eventually yielding data results.  The problem is that I've opened up a session that will not close until my entire outer transaction completes.  Every call to `getSession()` will create a new connection and I very quickly I run out of threads.  This is observed by MySQL>show processlist showing max connections I allow for BoneCP and Tomcat freezing after Obtaining a JDBC connection:

```
[2012-11-10 03:31:56,887] DEBUG [http-8443-exec-3] LogicalConnectionImpl.obtainConnection(295) | Obtaining JDBC connection
[2012-11-10 03:31:56,887] DEBUG [http-8443-exec-3] LogicalConnectionImpl.obtainConnection(301) | Obtained JDBC connection
```

Tomcat will sit like this forever.

The workaround appears to be aggressive connection management. I introduced `hibernate.connection.release_mode=after_statement` to my `<bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">` definition.

Only after_statement seems to work.  With this setting in place, the program executes w/o issues for trivial and non-trivial runs.  Note that `hibernate.current_session_context_class=thread` does not seem to have any impact. Overall using release_mode feels very hacky.  The need to aggressively release connections after each statement must have unwanted consequences for an app under load.

So - what is happening? Why doesn't `getCurrentSession()` return a session without an active Transaction bound to the Thread?  Is the `@Transactional` annotation the only way `hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean` can work out when to kick in a transaction?  Spring Docs seems to be very sparse on topic.

Further, switching down to `hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean` (and switching other configs referencing hibernate4 back to hibernate3) yields the nasty `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError`: `org/hibernate/cache/CacheProvider`, which is covered by other threads on stackoverflow.

Any ideas? Really appreciate some input. Thank you!